# LM2576 ON/OFF pin for over voltage protection

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, switching, zener, over-voltage-protection

I'm trying to shut down an LM2576 regulator in the event that one of its adjusting resistors fails open. I'd like to use the ON/OFF pin on the regulator as this seemed as though it should be easy and cheap, and stops the current rather than having it dissipated as heat. The input is between 5 and 37v, and if this resistor fails, it sends that voltage all the way through to the rest of my circuit, exploding capacitors and killing the processor.

The ON/Off pin needs 1.4v to start shutting down the regulator, which i'm able to feed from the 5.1v zener as in the schematic below (I hope it's below, this is my first post, sorry if i've got it wrong!) But it needs around 5v for full shutdown, which is what I'd like. The schematic is simplified obviously, there are capacitors and whatnot in there as needed by the LM2576

My problem is that by feeding it through the zener, it only limits the output to 6.7v, I assume because this is the voltage the zener needs to give the pin 1.4v. This is enough to stop things exploding, but not really to fully protect the circuit. If i give a direct 5v or 12v or whatever to the pin, it shuts it down completely. I've tried using the zener to feed a transistor, but this just ups the voltage to 7.2ish, and as the pin needs to be pulled high, i can't just use the transistor to go to GND.

I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't see it! Can anyone help please?!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCCLvp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqD8cj.png)</sup>

Comment: Why do you expect that the resistors may fail? A resistor failing, especially a feedback resistor that shouldn't have much current through it, is very rare.

Comment: I don't really expect them to, I agree it would be really rare, but it's for use in a boat, and it's going to get banged around a lot. The high voltage could also work it's way over from a stray wire or something, I'd just like to give a shutdown if that happened. I don't really want capacitors exploding at sea. It gave me a bit of surprise yesterday!

Answer (score 2):

If you use negative feedback to EN! With a threshold of 1.3V for OVP, it will oscillate from a over-voltage condition.  You may want to use a latch for this function with POR and an indicator.  Or some other autonomous retry method.

Make sure your step load response is stable with acceptable overshoot.

You might consider a current limiter on the input.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I'm not quite sure what you mean by a negative feedback to EN! But the idea of a latching POR has made me realise that I should probably just have another fuse of some sort triggered by a zener, as this situation means something needs to be reattached to the PCB. This means a much bigger zener that can handle the current though and I'm not sure it would all be fast enough to protect the caps and MCU. I suspect that the way i have it set up now is causing it to oscillate, but it sits there happily and the resettable fuse isn't triggered as there's hardly any current going through.

Comment: When EN! Goes above 1.3V output drops then EN! drops below 1.3 and output goes high .. this is a negative feedback relaxation oscillator if OV condition returns when enabled.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I believe this is the situation that I've arrived at so far. As the Zener provides the ON/OFF (Enable Input) pin with 1.4v, but only when the cathode of the zener has reached 6.66v, capping the PCB output at 6.66v, no doubt oscillating slightly above and below it. But really i need a way to increase that 1.4v in order to bring down the 6.66v to somewhere below 5. I can reduce the zener voltage to 4.7v, which will no doubt help (my circuit runs at 4v) But I think what you're suggesting is that I use a schmitt trigger or something in order to avoid the zener altogether?

Comment: Yes you can try all those but that won’t latch an OVP permanent failure . If it is an overshoot protection, then a better solution is needed. Test your regulator for overshoot to simulate a down step to sleep mode, then test with a cap failure (higher ESR), then figure out how to detect and report  a fault before it occurs and shutdown has occured

Comment: Great Ok thanks Tony, I'll re-think it. Perhaps a permanent fusable link and a high current zener is the sensible way.

Comment: Define your reliability requirements and design accordingly.

Comment: Smarter regulators have hiccup OCP protection

Comment: Well, essentially I want the regulator to turn off if over voltage is detected on the output. And at the moment, it's not doing this, it's protecting it, but it could last for years in this state without me ever knowing. I really really don't want a fire on a boat! I already have TVS diodes for transients so thats not the issue.

Comment: Try PNP Emitter to 4V output with 4V on Vb? And collector pulldown to EN! ? That gives you gain on feedback. Use a large RC for hiccup. Or a Darlington PNP with 3.3 on Vb or even a 3.1V LED that can be trimmed to 10 or 15% OVP

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I think you mean almost the same as in my second schematic, but with a PNP instead of NPN as the emitter in the PNP needs to be higher voltage than the base/collector in order to conduct, whereas I've got NPN and so I'm stuck below the base/collector voltage, which for the 5.1v zener is 1.4v?

Comment: Not the same . PNP common base amp with gain vs NPN Emitter followers with gain =1

Comment: Although better solutions exist, if you are going this route trim Vb threshold to detect 150mV above regulated output. Beware of heat rise in Regulator

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I understand from Tony's suggestion is this. I possibly just need to use a PNP transistor rather than NPN, as this will give me more voltage to the ON/OFF pin when it's triggered by the zener:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnJ7U9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hmm, drawing it out the way i understand it has made me realise that this will still just oscillate the output at 5.1v again and never actually turn the regulator off. So I think I might be looking in the wrong direction really. So, does anyone have any opinion on this latching version? Its getting a bit big, but I think I've got room:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ceQw.png)</sup>

If the output voltage rises above 5.1v, the zener triggers the NPN, pulling the PNP to GND, which in turn sends the unregulated voltage (up to 40v) to the ON/OFF pin and back to the NPN through the bottom resistor, turning off the regulator and keeping it off until the 40v is turned off. I've seen a few of these schematics, but sometimes they omit the cap and R2, and I can't really see any need for them. Transients from the unregulated supply might damage the transistors I suppose, but i can't see how they can trigger them accidentally. obviously they need to be rated for over 40v.

Comment: I was wrong , high gain positive feedback is what I meant with positive logic to disable rather than is high gain negative feedback for negative logic to disable.  But in any case high gain is what you needed rather than unity gain and cap. memory rather than FF memory.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is trying to do the same, this works:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJJYi2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It needs the pull-down R2 to stop Q1 accidentally closing, and it needs C3 in order to reset. Otherwise the residual voltage left in the power supply capacitors C2 can hold it closed even when power is removed from the system, making it impossible to reset.

Once the latch has been sent (which it does at 5.3 V), it turns off the regulator, but that still outputs enough current at 2.4 V to keep the latched closed, and the ON/OFF pin high, and so it's possible to use the regulated output from the LM2576 to feed Q2 rather than the unregulated output which could be running at 40 V or whatever.